# How can I conditionally format my HTML table?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, string

```
<td Class='metric' title='Test gave a performance metric.' lastPassTag=''>1997.0</td>
<td Class='metric' title='Test gave a performance metric.' lastPassTag=''>1997.0</td>
<td Class='metric' title='Test gave a performance metric.' lastPassTag=''>1997.0</td>
<td Class='metric' title='Test gave a performance metric.' lastPassTag=''>1997.0</td>
</tr><tr class='detail-hide'><td Class='result-name '>pmu: COMMITTED_PKT_BSB</td>
<td Class='metric' title='Test gave a performance metric.' lastPassTag=''>1655.0</td>
<td Class='metric' title='Test gave a performance metric.' lastPassTag=''>1836.0</td>
<td Class='metric' title='Test gave a performance metric.' lastPassTag=''>1655.0</td>
<td Class='metric' title='Test gave a performance metric.' lastPassTag=''>1836.0</td>
```

I have a HTML table like above 
I'm trying to do conditional formatting based on the formula applied on the numbers there 
I tried this:

```
var tb = document.getElementByClass('metric')
```

I could not get those values
Any modifications or suggestions are appreciated 
Thank you

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("metric")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the only problem with your code is you are using wrong js context to search for class using js.

> document.getElementByClass('metric')

as classes can be more then 1 so the context to select class is having elements instead of element like below
**It should be Elements(Plural) not Element(Singular)**

> document.get**Elements**ByClass('metric')

hope this will solve your query.

if need any other help, just comment here I will try to solve

Comment: Thanks . And can you please tell me how I can see the content obtained

Comment: @Ganga you can use console.log(tb); and this will display all the contents in your console window

Comment: @Ganga hope this will help. or you can also use document.write(tb).innerHTML; to display its content on browser.

Comment: for (var index = 0; index < tb.length; index++) {
    document.write(tb[index]).innerHTML; 
} When I try this I'm getting [object HTML table size Element ]

Comment: I wanted the inner content

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189575/discussion-between-nitin-garg-and-ganga).

Answer (score 2):

The method is wrong - you want to use `document.getElementsByClassName`:

```
var tb = document.getElementByClass("metric");
```

You could also use `querySelectorAll` to only get `td` elements with the class `metric`:

```
var tb = document.querySelectorAll("td.metric");
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems :

**1)** You miss first `<tr>` and last `</tr>` and also must wrap your `tr`s in `table` tag .

**2)**
Change :

```
document.getElementByClass('metric') ;
```

To:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('metric') ;
```

```js
var tb = document.getElementsByClassName('metric') ;

console.log(tb) ;
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td class='metric' title='Test gave a performance metric.' lastPassTag=''>1997.0</td>
  <td Class='metric' title='Test gave a performance metric.' lastPassTag=''>1997.0</td>
  <td Class='metric' title='Test gave a performance metric.' lastPassTag=''>1997.0</td>
  <td Class='metric' title='Test gave a performance metric.' lastPassTag=''>1997.0</td>
</tr>
<tr class='detail-hide'><td Class='result-name '>pmu: COMMITTED_PKT_BSB</td>
  <td Class='metric' title='Test gave a performance metric.' lastPassTag=''>1655.0</td>
  <td Class='metric' title='Test gave a performance metric.' lastPassTag=''>1836.0</td>
  <td Class='metric' title='Test gave a performance metric.' lastPassTag=''>1655.0</td>
  <td Class='metric' title='Test gave a performance metric.' lastPassTag=''>1836.0</td>
</tr>
</table>
```